# small arrow button in css

Tags: html, css, button, css-shapes

I have a design below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS.

[image]

The above design is basically a text with arrow button at the left.

I have replicated the text in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugd8ooth/show/) (which is extremely simple).  I am wondering how can I put the arrow left to the text ?

I tried following this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp) from w3schools but somehow I wasn't able to replicate the same arrow.

The CSS code for the text (which I have used in the fiddle):

```
.share {
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4676F2;
}
```

Comment: What code have you already tried yourself, to add the arrow? Also, please include the source for your arrow so we can help - i.e. is in an image, a font icon, encoded image?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I tried using HTML codes from there but still I wasn't able to replicate the same arrow.

Comment: If you want to use a specific arrow, you will have to find its source. I don't see the the arrow you have in your image anywhere in the W3schools page you linked to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the other answer, this one lays the font entity out right.

As discussed in your comments above, the arrow is not the same exact one you are looking for.  You need to cut it out and create an image to add to the image tag, or find the source of the image in text form.

```css
.share {
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4676F2;
}
.share p::before {
  content: "\27A6";
  color:#000;
  padding-right:8px;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.share p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="share">
            <p>Share This Article</p>
</div>

<div class="share">
            <p><img src=""/>Share This Article</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you check, it doesn't look similar to the design.

Comment: Looks pretty similar but in the design its very fat. Can we somehow increase the size of it ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code. The unicode arrow is not precisely the way you mocked-up but close. If you need the arrow to be precise, you can switch the `.share::before` rule to use a background image.

```css
.share {
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4676F2;
}

.share::before {
  content: "\27A6";
  color:#000;
  padding-right:8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="share">Share This Article</div>
```

Comment: Looks pretty similar but in the design its very fat. Can we somehow increase the size of it ?

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can create an image that is exactly like you need. I'm not sure you'll be able to find a perfect match using unicode. Try a background image.